# How to really blink an LED on an arduino through ROS

Tags: ros, arduino, multiple, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up ROS with an arduino and successfully implemented the blink-example. However, I would like to really make it blink, e.g. to turn the LED on and off with a high frequency. Unfortunately, I have not managed to do that. The code I tried is:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){
digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));
delay(100);
digitalWrite(13, LOW-digitalRead(13));
delay(100); // blink the led
}

 ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("toggle_led", &messageCb );

void setup()
{ 
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
nh.initNode();
nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop() 
{  
nh.spinOnce();
}
```

As can be seen, I tried to give the command to be executed in the message as if the message contains the actions to be carried out, but it did not work so I was wondering what the proper way to do sequences of action with one message would be?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270917/how-to-really-blink-an-led-on-an-arduino-through-ros/) by [paulrusu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31910/paulrusu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that you got some inspiration from this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink#The_Code

The line

```
digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));
```

will toggle the LED for you. First, it reads the pin `digitalRead(13)`, then it writes it `digitalWrite`. The portion that says `HIGH-digitalRead(13)` does the alternating part. If  `digitalRead(13)` is high then your LED will turn off and if it's low your LED will turn on.

- `HIGH - HIGH = LOW` therefore turn off LED
- `HIGH - LOW = HIGH` therefore turn on LED

The callback is the trigger for this behavior. Therefore, all you need to do to get your LED to blink at a high frequency is to publish an `std_msgs/Empty` message along the `toggle_led` topic at whatever rate you want.

Now, about the `delay`s. You should remove them and just do it how the tutorial showed it. Callbacks should be quick so that you can react to the incoming messages. With two `delay`s of 100ms each you won't be able to blink the LED at a high frequency.

---

**Edit:**

I'd be cautious about looping in a callback like so:

```
void messageCb( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){
  for (int thisInt = 1; thisInt < 2000; thisInt++) {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH-digitalRead(8)); delay(100); 
  // blink the led
  }
}
```

The reason is that callbacks should be quick in order to react to incoming messages. But, here the loop is running for almost 200s! You're going to be in that function for over 3 minutes not doing anything else, ignoring all subsequent messages. Now, for this use case you're ok because it's trivial. But, for anything of consequence this is going to cause you trouble. Usually, I'd say an [action](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) is the way to go, but `rosserial_arduino` doesn't support that (as far as I know) so you'll either have to write another node to control the publishing of the message that controls the blinking or find another workaround.

Otherwise, your first code block looks like it works.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
@paulrusu: if this solved your problem, please click the check mark to mark it as correct.

**Comment by [paulrusu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31910/paulrusu/) on 2017-09-16**:
Thank you for your answer, but this was not quite what I meant. Obviously, I understand that every time one publishes a message, the LED is turned on or off. It is a switch. What I was interested in was the usage of one message to trigger a whole array of actions and not just one.